# Jmeter error http test script recorder with Firestore Request

Tags: firebase, firefox, google-cloud-firestore, jmeter, performance-testing

I am testing a website that is using firestore.googleapis.com services, at some point I am blocked and I can't proceed to the test, due to this error from the firestore request:

[image: Jmeter response data]

Here's a copy of the request body:

[image: Jmeter Request Body]

I also did some troubleshooting with Firefox Developers Tools and I found this error on console:

[image: Firefox Console Log]

My configurations:

- Jmeter Version: 5.4.1
- Firefox Version: 85.0.2

Firefox is configured with Proxy so I can catch all the responses in the jmeter in port 8080 with HTTP test script recorder.

This just happens when I have the proxy configured in Firefox. If I turn the proxy off, the website works perfectly, already uninstall jmeter and remove certificates and add new ones, but the error appears always.

I have already tried Edge and Chrome with proxy configured, but with no success.

How can I "bypass" or fix this problem with firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore?

Comment: Please attach text instead of screenshot when it is possible. For example, you can put the `request body` and the `error message` as text in this post. It's hard to read it from the screenshot at this font size.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your [Firefox browsing data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox), it might be the case Firebase connection is blocked by [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security%5C) so your first visit to the website you're testing should be "clean".

Also if there is no essential data in the Firebase I would recommend skipping recording requests to it (as well as to other 3rd-party websites) as you load test should solely focus on your application. You can filter out the domains which shouldn't be in your test scope via "URL Patterns to Exclude" section of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

[image]

In the unlikely case of above hints don't help be aware of the alternative way of recording a JMeter test - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), it's not that "invasive" as JMeter so you shouldn't see any impact on your web application functionality.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work, i have uninstall firefox and installed again, import jmeter certificate, and the result is the same, i have put the url in the "URL Patterns to Exclude" but gets stuck in the same request.
This is some how related with the proxy, Blazemeter plugin recording is ok capturing the request from firestore, but i can't collect the logs in blazemeter plugin and i need the logs.